# Как скопировать репозиторий с bitbucket?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, ssh-key

Имеется репозиторий на bitbucket.com http://prntscr.com/h86ay0 С таким содержимым http://prntscr.com/h86bg1.

Локальный комп на винде. В папке c:/users/MyName/.ssh сгенерил ключи emk_rsa и emk_rsa.pub и залил последний на bitbucket http://prntscr.com/h86e1q, указал хосты bitbucket в файле c:/users/MyName/.ssh/config

Также сделал еще один ключ и добавил его в основные настройки.

Использую Cygwin, пытаюсь клонировать репозиторий с bitbucket по инструкции https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/clone-a-repository-223217891.html командой
$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:mynamespace/emk.git

В ответ получаю сообщение:

> Cloning into 'emk'...
> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: eval "$(ssh-agent -s)";
ssh-add ~/.ssh/emk_rsa

Comment: Добавил оба ключа, не помогло, к сожалению. Спасибо.

Comment: ssh -T git@bitbucket.com что выдает?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/h8762r

Comment: Ключ рабочий, аутефикация происходит. В чем проблема не могу сказать. На крайний варинт может стоит поставить офицальный гит клиент и с него попробовать.

Answer (score -1):

попробуй вот так:

```
git clone ssh://git@bitbucket.org/mynamespace/emk
```